# How can I display a Power View report without a frame in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, powerview

The question is almost asked in the title but some more detail:

I've created in a Power Pivot Gallery a connection to my Tabular model and a Power View report. The report looks great, I think Power Pivot/Power View is a pretty cool technology, etc. etc.

I look at videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onYoGNKyiLw) and I see a gorgeous report without the ugly frame and I can't help but think... how basic is this? The best I can do so far is putting a link to the report in a web page Web Part and it looks hideous. I want this to be part of a dashboard, if possible, though a Power View report already kind of fulfills that function.

Not only that, but my google-fu is failing me. There's tutorials for putting up PerformancePoint stuff for a dashboard but I can't find a step by step for this.

I know Sharepoint questions are frowned upon it seems but that SO sub-domain seems dead. A link to a tutorial or a basic explanation should be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question! I'm also trying to do this and I can't find a good tutorial either, not sure if this will help but here's what I have so far:

**Step 1**

Site Settings > Manage Site Features

- Enable BICenter Data Connections Feature
- Enable PerformancePoint Services

**Step 2**

Site Contents > add an app

- Add DataConnections Library for PerformancePoint
- Add PerformancePoint Content List

**Step 3**

Go into your instance of PerformancePoint Content List

- Click PERFORMANCEPOINT in the ribbon
- Click Dashboard Designer

**Step 4**

This is where the blind leads the blind, welcome to the bleeding edge!

So inside Dashboard Designer on the left panel (Workspace Browser), you should see the instances of DataConnections and PerformancePoint that you just created. Select the DataConnection. At the top you'll see Home/Edit/Create - click Create then Data Source (which might be the only choice currently enabled, it is for me).

Now you can choose to import data from SQL, Excel, a SP List, etc...I've tried several options but no matter what I do, I get this error message: "*Cannot connect to PerformancePoint Services. Contact the administrator for details.*"

Hope this will at least point you in the right direction for now. If I can solve that error and continue on, I'll come back with more steps for you.

Comment: Upvoted just for answering, I'll give you a green check if this leads anywhere. Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks @Ryanman, did some more digging last night and this seems to be relevant, you might check these settings on your system:
SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management > Service Applications > Configure Service Application Associations > Default > Application Proxy Group > Performance Point (if it's not selected, go ahead and turn that on)